# How to use ListView in CardView?

Tags: java, android, listview, retrofit

How to use ListView in CardView ? I have CardView, CardView and then in CardView I would like to add ListView that ListView data come from server.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView...>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView...>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Ingredients"/>

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/list_name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        </ListView>

                </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity_listview.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void GetNames() {
        NetworkEngine.getInstance().getStudent(student.getId(), new Callback<List<Student>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Student> students, Response response) {
              //  Student student = students;
              //  ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter<>(getApplication(), R.layout.activity_listview, students);
            //    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_name);
             //   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem then ??

Comment: I want to add ListView in CardView and then show data in ListView

Comment: Be clear @PeterPhyo if you want to create a `ListView` in `CardView` than where is the problem? just initialise the `ListView` in Java `Activity` and set the `Adapter` done!

Comment: Your `ListView` is already there in `CardView`. What is the problem in that??